# Mockito NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

I followed what @hoaz suggested. However, I am getting nullpointer exception

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class GeneralConfigServiceImplTest  {

@InjectMocks private GeneralConfigService generalConfigService;
@Mock private SomeDao someDao;
@Mock private ExternalDependencyClass externalDependencyObject 

@Test
public void testAddGeneralConfigCallDAOSuccess() {
    when(someDao.findMe(any(String.Class))).thenReturn(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("1234")));

    //println works here, I am able to get collection from my mocked DAO

    // Calling the actual service function
    generalConfigService.process(externalDependencyObject)
    }
}
```

In my Code it's like this:

```
import com.xyz.ExternalDependencyClass;

public class  GeneralConfigService{

private SomeDao someDao;

public void process(ExternalDependencyClass externalDependencyObject){

// function using Mockito 
Collection<String> result = someDao.findMe(externalDependencyObject.getId.toString())
    }
}
```

I also notice that DAO was null so I did this(Just to mention, I did the below step to try, I know the difference between springUnit and Mockito or xyz):

```
@Autowired
private SomeDao someDao;
```

---

@John B solution solved my problem. However I would like to mention what did not work for me. This is my updated unit test

```
@Test
public void testAddGeneralConfigCallDAOSuccess() {
    /*
    This does not work
    externalDependencyObject.setId(new ExternalKey("pk_1"));
    // verify statement works and I thought that the class in test when call the getId 
    // it will be able to get the ExternalKey object
    //verify(externalDependencyObject.setId(new ExternalKey("pk_1")));
    */

    // This works
    when(externalDependencyObject.getId()).thenReturn(new ExternalKey("pk_1"));
    when(someDao.findMe(any(String.Class))).thenReturn(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("1234")));

    ....
    // Calling the actual service function
    generalConfigService.process(externalDependencyObject)
    }
```

---

Referenced this question in :

[How do I mock external method call with Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14269502/how-do-i-mock-external-method-call-with-mockito)

[How do I set a property on a mocked object using Mockito?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19920271/how-to-set-a-property-of-mocked-object-using-mockito/24071714#24071714)

Comment: Why are you mocking something that you're autowiring?  It *smells* like this should be either a pure Spring-style integration test, or a pure mock test.

Comment: I tried to do @Autowired step to since I was running into the exception of NullPointer, but it's running into exception even after that. I see that when the `someDao.findMe(someObject.getId.toString())` execute it does NOT trigger my MockDao return statement, but instead tries to evaluate `someObject.getId.toString()`. When I did println in the test for  `someDao.findMe` it does return the collection. I also checked the debugging, `someDao` is already set property into generalConfigService. So not sure why it's evaluating and not just returning my collection

Answer (score 12):

You haven't mocked the behavior of `getId` in `externalDependencyObject` therefore it is returning `null` and giving you the NPE when `toString()` is called on that `null`.

You need a `when(externalDependencyObject.getId()).then...`